# What is the difference between a data type widget and a stateless widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm quite new to flutter and I'm trying to figure out the best way to build my widgets in the aspect of good performance while I have three choices:
1- `Stateful Wigdet`.
2- `Stateless Widget`.
3- `Widget function(){}` with a `StatefulBuilder` if needed.
Thanks.

Comment: visit here'https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-stateless-and-stateful-widget-in-flutter/

Answer (score 0):

A `StatefulWidget` has `State`, which means that you can change stuff inside the widget without needing to destroy it and create a new version. They work slower than `StatelessWidget` but are better for checkboxes or screens which need to be frequently updated.

A `StatelessWidget` is locked, and you cannot change values once it is initiated. In order to change things inside the widget, you need to re-call the `build` function to build an updated version. They are quite fast but are best used for static screens.

`Widget function(){}` widgets are custom-made. Essentially, you can take any existing widget and modify it, adding childs and other widgets to it. However, the widget type normally inherits from a `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget`. These can cover basically everything.